# How to get the amount of time viewed and megabytes of video on youtube?

Tags: javascript, firefox, youtube, firefox-addon-webextensions

How to get the amount of time viewed and megabytes of video on youtube in real time? Use javascript (from browser extension).

I know i can click "Debug info" from page with video, but it only copy to clipboard...

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: i can get only lenght video, but can't get viewed size in mb/gb